# JavaScript using image only on local user

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, server, todataurl

I'd like to understand how Image work in JavaScript.

When you create an image like this:

```
this.image = new Image();
this.image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Is the image loaded only on the user computer or does it go on the server side?

Because I'd like to create images only on user side to optimize the canvas render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code creates a new `Image` object and stores it into a variable.

```
 this.image = new Image();
```

This bit of code stores your toDataURL() to your .src property within your `image` variable. Here's some documentation on the `.src` property.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp

```
this.image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Because you have created the variables locally then it will not be stored on the server. Essentially you're storing the URL for the image, based on current code. You can change the type to say `toDataUrl(image/jpeg)` and even scale the quality with overloads in the method `toDataURL(image/jpeg, 1.0)` Check out this helpful article on the `.toDataURL()` method and what it does more specifically.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL